# Security loophole in Google Document List API

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client

Currently, I am using HttpClient + XML parser, to consume Google Document List API 3.

```
URL url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3");
URLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("client_id", your client id);
conn.addRequestProperty("client_secret", your client secret);
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
```

What I realize that, even I do not supply `Client Id`, `Client secret` or even `Simple API key` (I only supply authentication token), I still can communicate with Google Doc (Google Drive) no problem at all. I can still download and upload files.

May I know, why is it so? Is this security loop hole in Google API?

Comment: Perhaps the auth token is sufficient? What happens when you omit that too?

Comment: Auth token is a must and I cannot omit that. However, I can omit client id, client secret or even simple API key. Google needs those info to keep track application usage of its API. Now, even I do not supply to Google, I still can use their service, which makes me feel very weird.

Comment: How do you obtain the auth token?  Normally, in order to obtain it, you'd need to log in (most likely using OAUTH).  Thus, as you already get the token, it means you have successfully logged in and the token intrinsically refers to a specific client ID, etc.  I agree this is still not the best thing ever, as you could potentially re-use the token across apps.

Comment: I obtain auth token through GoogleAccountManager. If so, Google unable to keep track the usage of its API, by specific App. It can only know its API is being consumed by Android, but not by which app.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the OAuth access token to access the APIs. But the access token is only valid for one hour. Then you will need the refresh token and client secret to generate a new one.

[Check the OAuth2 doc for more info](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)